# Dell Latitude E6420 in-built microphone not working

Tags: 12.04, sound, 64-bit, microphone, hda-intel

I'm running with Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on Dell Latitude E6420.
The inbuilt microphone is not working, and is not listed on the sound settings dialog.

According to lspci, the device is:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

I've also looked at alsamixer, and can see a "mic" and "dock mic" but fiddling with these and increasing to max amplification doesn't appear to change anything.

Note: I've raised a certification question on the same topic here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/200678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mitch,

You will note from the linked certification question that the problem has been resolved.  My theory is that it is a problem that fixed once I had installed the proprietary nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

According to Dell there is a driver that fixes this issue.  The have it listed ion their website.  It fixes internal microphone on E55xx series 3rd generation latitudes.

You can download it [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=H99J1&FileId=2731100373&productCode=latitude-e6420&urlProductCode=False)